# Firefox Add-On know install failure log

Tags: firefox-addon, xul

There is a way to know why an add on has failed to install ?

I've developed a XUL add-on and placed on firefox. The browser tell me that want to install application and i accept and restart browser.

After restart, my add on isnt displayed and i know if the proble is chrome.manifest, xul file or other.

There is a way to log "install" problem and know where is the installation error ?

Answer (score 0):

Press Ctrl + Shift + J, which opens the browser console, click "Clear" it empties it, then install your addon and look for messages in there. If it fails you'll usually see something like "WARN ...."

Comment: When i drag my addon in Firefox the console show only a series of log like: Starting install, Stage install and removetemporaryFile. I think this isnt errors. After this, i have to restart the browser to see if the installations is works or not. Fore sure, when i restart the browser console will be closed and if i repone it, this dont show anything and the addon isnt present

Comment: If you open the browser console and dont clear it you can look for your messages. The console does get cut off after 200 messages so you can increase that limit see here: https://ask.mozilla.org/question/459/prevent-browser-console-from-discarding-message/